# reporting R crashes as bugs

Tags: r

Recently I am crashing R relatively often. The message is invariably

```
*** caught segfault ***
address xxx, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

Reproducing would be hard, and in any case I could not share the large proprietary data sets. My question is: can I report the crash so that it is investigated? Would generating the coredump help? It seems that the FAQ section on reporting bugs is not meant for this contingency.

Comment: At a minimum you should add sessionInfo() to this question, and report what is happening: are you reading from a database, file, writing etc?

Comment: Thanks to all who answered. It's not possible to run sessionInfo() after a segfault. My code uses a large number of packages (RODBC, zoo, plyr, reshape, ggplot2), some of which either use C (zoo, RODBC), or call heavily C routines (ggplot, calling grid). I was wondering if it's possible to identify the offending package.

Comment: the analogous contents reported by sessionInfo() would do, it's not technically necessary to actually run it, it's just a super lazy way to provide basic information so I guess we should beat your head with an actual stick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't report them to R-core / R-devel unless you're 100% certain it's a bug in R and not a package.  It's more likely the bug is in a package you're using.  If you can't create a reproducible example of the bug, the package maintainer isn't likely to try to hunt it down.

Comment: To amplify: start by finding a reproducible example (if necessary, create a batch file that runs the same analysis many times until a crash occurs).  Then narrow down the scenario: how small a set of contributed packages can you use and still provoke the crash?  Can you make it happen with an equal-sized set of random, anonymized, or randomized data?

Answer (score 4):

This error message can occur with

1. Hardware overheating
2. Using outdated versions of R or of packages
3. A bug in a package
4. A bug in R

Until you can reproduce it, with fake data if you don't want to expose your own, that I doubt anyone will pay attention to a crash report.

Answer (score 1):

The 'memory not mapped' text leads to a strong suspicion of this being a systems issue: either one of OS, C library or BLAS could be at stake.

It is frustrating with large compute jobs -- but there is no other way than to distill it to a minimal reproducible example, which you could do with mocked-up data too.

As a start, try to see if the problem persists on a different OS, eg try re-running it on a mac or a different linux flavour or windoze.