# What can I do about frequent, unreproducible segfault errors in R 3.0.1?

Tags: r, segmentation-fault

After upgrading to R 3.0.X, I've started getting pretty frequent, unreproducible segfault errors like those found by this [asker.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6512570/reporting-r-crashes-as-bugs)  I never had one of these errors before with R 2.X.X. For example, this is the session info for a long block of code that just caused a fault.  However, after R crashed, I ran the entire block of code again and there was no error.

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] klaR_0.6-8      ggplot2_0.9.3.1 labdsv_1.5-0    MASS_7.3-26     mgcv_1.7-22    
 [6] cluster_1.14.4  sparcl_1.0.3    FD_1.0-11       vegan_2.0-7     permute_0.7-0  
[11] geometry_0.3-3  magic_1.5-4     abind_1.4-0     ape_3.0-8       ade4_1.5-2     
[16] plyr_1.8       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] class_7.3-7        colorspace_1.2-2   dichromat_2.0-0    digest_0.6.3      
 [5] e1071_1.6-1        grid_3.0.1         gtable_0.1.2       labeling_0.1      
 [9] lattice_0.20-15    Matrix_1.0-12      munsell_0.4        nlme_3.1-109      
[13] proto_0.3-10       RColorBrewer_1.0-5 reshape2_1.2.2     scales_0.2.3      
[17] stringr_0.6.2
```

Sometimes R freezes completely and I have to do a force quit, but other times, it allows me to exit with options for a core dump or saving the workspace.

Someone in another post suggested setting `options(CBoundsCheck=T)` and that seemed to work for a while but I am still getting frequent faults.

I don't think these faults are related to any specific kind of calculation or function as I got one the other day after starting a new session and only setting my working directory and options.  The code that triggered the fault and the system info would look like this:

```
#Set my working directory
setwd("~/Documents/School Spring 2013/Quaternary Dissasembly/Functional Diversity Basefile 3")

#Keep getting segfaults all the time. This might fix it
options(CBoundsCheck=T)



sessionInfo()

R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Any help anyone could give me to find and fix the bug or the incorrect settings I have would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

-M

Comment: Follow the instructions in the [Using gctorture and memory access](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Using-gctorture-and-memory-access) and [Debugging compiled code](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Debugging-compiled-code) sections of the Debugging section of [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html).

Comment: I had the same issue. 3.0.2 fixed it immediately.